# Java's Graphics.drawImage produces an inaccurate image

Tags: java, image, rendering

I'm trying to draw one image onto another using `graphics.drawImage()` but it's only working accurately for some images, others it messes up. My code's below, I've made sure `texture` is the right image when it enters the method so that's definitely not it. Any ideas?

```
private BufferedImage currentSheet;
public void swapRegionWithTexture(Rectangle region, Image texture) {
    Graphics sheetGraphics = currentSheet.createGraphics();
    for (int ix = region.x; ix < region.x + region.width; ix++) {
        for (int iy = region.y; iy < region.y + region.height; iy++) {
            currentSheet.setRGB(ix, iy, 0x000000);
        }
    }
    sheetGraphics.drawImage(texture, region.x, region.y, null);
    sheetGraphics.dispose();
}
```

The general idea is:

1. Grab the graphics to draw to.
2. Clear out the section of the graphics that will be drawn on.
3. Draw the image at the given location on the graphics.
4. Dispose of the graphics.

Comment: can you define inaccurate? perhaps provide screenshots of desired and actual outputs?

Comment: It seems like an alpha issue. Have you tried to change the `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`?

Comment: Yeah, it just completely removes the alpha channel.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Z89fC - An imgur gallery of the before and after. Sorry if they're small, it's a Minecraft-based project.

Answer (score 0):

Your current atomic steps are thus:

- create a new buffered image
- write to that buffered image some crazy manipulation of the original texture (looks like you're reversing it?)
- write the **original** image to the current sheet.

So what if you change this

```
sheetGraphics.drawImage(texture, region.x, region.y, null);
```

to this

```
sheetGraphics.drawImage(bufferedTexture, region.x, region.y, null);
```

Otherwise you're spending time reversing the image and putting into buffered texture and then never doing anything with that buffer... so chances are you intended to use that buffered texture somewhere.

Comment: Hah! Thanks for pointing that out, I **just** tried this new, bizarre strategy before I posted so I missed that part because it was my original attempt.

However, it's not working. I still get the inaccurate result. I wish I could post images, but I can't yet apparently. The best I can do is say that it appears to become more pixelated after the procedure and it's not always the result, the majority of the time it works as intended.

As for the bizarre method, I'm just converting it into a BufferedImage in order to get the actual RGB value at a given point.

Comment: you can upload them to tiny pic and put the links in the comments.

Comment: Ah, there we go. I can't really pin what's going on, feels like a lower quality, but some get their colors messed up or wind up shades of gray.

Comment: It looks like your alpha is getting messed up somewhere, honestly. I'm currently researching how to transfer that over, and that might be where you want to direct your efforts as well.

Comment: Just uploaded a video of a few images that are affected, the alpha doesn't seem to be the problem. http://youtu.be/bnEZkUBsnZE

Comment: Unfortunately, youtube is streaming media and is nixxed at the worksite for bandwidth reasons.